# Unhandled promise rejection error from node.js using sendgrid npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js

What might be the cause? Node is giving me unhandled promise rejection error what is wrong with the code.

The sendgrid module has been required successfully and the sendgrid API key has been set correctly but the code is still giving me error.

```
sgMail.send({
    to: 'somebody@gmail.com',
    from: 'somebodygmail.com',
    subject: 'This is my first creation!',
    text: 'I hope this one actually get to you'
})
```

Comment: Are you executing this on a node server such as express or in a browser application like React, Vue, or Angular? The error is related to CORS https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/

Comment: Yes on an express node server

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```js
sgMail.send({
    to: 'somebody@gmail.com',
    from: 'somebodygmail.com',
    subject: 'This is my first creation!',
    text: 'I hope this one actually get to you'
}).then(out=>console.log(out)).catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

You'll be able to identify the error. if not, then post the log to the question.

**Edit:**

possible cause:

**from** email is invalid

Comment: yes here it is ``` code: 403,
  message: 'Forbidden',
  response: {
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Sat, 25 Apr 2020 00:46:56 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '281',
      connection: 'close',```

Comment: another part of it ``` connection: 'close',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
      'access-control-max-age': '600',
      'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html'
    },
    body: { errors: [Array] }
  }
}
 ```

Comment: is your from email is valid?

Comment: my email. is valid